Looking for alternative on COUNTIF >0 formula on GOOGLE SHEET to automatic count diff cell in columns I add everyday
I was working on 15 to 20 sheets of data mainly for budget for Online Campaigns. Each sheet have like 5 to 10 tables of campaigns containing its budget for the day.I have this Ad Status sheet out of the rest where I get to count how many campaigns for a specific day have used up the budget. Automatically not countaing those who have 0 spending. But the problem is, as I add new column everyday, I also have to alter the formula I used for this which is very taxing.
For Reference here's a practice sheet.
I'm so sorry if this sounds confusing. I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!
I tried using COUNTIF(DATA1!A1,">0")+COUNTIF(DATA1!A2,">0") but this is very time consuming since I have to add atleast 10 to 15 new columns everyday which means I have to add the new columns into this formula again and again. If there's any way to save time on this, any solution you have, will greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much!!

Use COUNTIFS() and refer full row. You may try-
=COUNTIFS('DATA 1'!C7:7,">0",'DATA 1'!C6:6,"Cost")



Yes! That definitely did it. Thanks once again! <3
